# How to check if vars(object) is of type dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am having a little trouble checking if vars(object) is of type dictionary. If it's not of type dictionary, than it will throw an error for doing vars(object):

```
if type(vars(vars(self.j)['element'])) is dict:  # exception gets thrown here if not a dictionary
    'this is a dictionary'
```

you can't use type(vars(object)) if vars(object) not a dictionary. so how do you check if vars(object) is a dictonary?

edit: in response to the answer below:

```
print type(vars(self.j)['element'])
print isinstance(vars(vars(self.j)['element']), dict)  # this is a dict
print type(vars(self.j)['beverage'])
print isinstance(vars(vars(self.j)['beverage']), dict) # exception thrown because its not a dictionary
```

output:

```
<class '__main__.Element2'>
True
<type 'str'>

    print isinstance(vars(vars(self.j)['beverage']), dict)
TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute
```

edit: in response to bruno, I want to do something like this:

```
def are_elements_equal(self, first_element, second_element, msg=None):
    for i in vars(first_element).keys():
        if type(vars(vars(first_element)[i])) is dict:
                self.are_elements_equal(vars(first_element)[i], vars(second_element)[i])
        else:
            self.assertEqual(vars(first_element)[i], vars(second_element)[i])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming `obj` as a `__dict__` attribute, `var(obj)` will return a `dict`  - or eventually a `dict_proxy` if called on a class. BUT neither a `dict` nor a `dict_proxy` have a `__dict__`, so `vars(vars(obj))` WILL obviously raise a `TypeError` - in the inner call if `obj` as no `__dict__`, else in the outer call.

You could of course handle the exception with a try/except block, but since this will ALWAYS raise, it would be quite pointless. So the real problem is: **why** do you think you want to use `vars(vars(obj))` at all ?

Comment: check the edit. I tried to answer your question as to why I want to use vars(vars(obj))

Comment: here is my full code if you want to see it: http://www.codesend.com/view/9515db7496c9b3d36fd49231a5684f08/